# how to get system.out.println() work in hadoop

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop

I am trying to debug in hadoop. I want to print some variables out to terminal with System.out.println(), but nothing has been output to the terminal. I checked the jobhistory/logs under

```
http://serverurl:19888/jobhistory/app
```

but still only INFOs there, no println()s. Furthermore, I have modified log4j.properties, changed

```
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
```

to

```
hadoop.root.logger=ALL,console
```

but still not working.

Anyone has some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: the printouts will be in task tracker logs (map or reducer, based on where you put print), from job tracker click on job id and further on map or reduce task and you will see the logs.

Comment: @rVr I see. I didn't click into Map or Reduce, now I find them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you define a logger and print the output through the logger?

```
 public class Log4jExample{ 
     static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                  log4jExample.class.getName());

      public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException,SQLException{
         log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
         log.info("Hello this is an info message");
      }
 }
```